# Enviar torpedos aos amigos

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

O que significa **Enviar torpedos aos amigos**?

Vi no texto

> Enquanto ela estudava, enviava torpedos aos amigos.

Pelo o que que vi no dicionário o **torpedo** como bomba não faz sentido aqui. Procurando no internet vi que tem outro significado mas não percebi o que.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Torpedo" é um dos nomes dado no Brasil aos "[SMS](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servi%C3%A7o_de_mensagens_curtas)".

Segundo o dicionário online [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/torpedo):

> 2. Mensagem curta enviada por meio de telefone celular

Os *torpedos* também podem ser chamados de "mensagem de texto".

Comment: Perfeito! Obrigado!
Só esse é formal?

Comment: Tchi... não sei, Majid. Sou de Portugal. Não aceites a resposta ainda, espera um ou dois dias - assim talvez outra pessoa responda também, e tenhas uma resposta ainda melhor! :)

Comment: É *um* nome, "mensagem de texto" é outro. Se não me engano foi a empresa [TIM](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIM_Brasil) que introduziu o termo para seus SMSs.

Answer (score 0):

Exato!
Torpedo é SMS - Short Message Service ou seja mensagens de texto.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, Rodrigo! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas eu diria que tua resposta pouco adiciona à [resposta anterior](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/7793/2764) do ANeves - nesse caso é preferível dar um voto positivo à resposta já existente do que postar uma nova com o mesmo conteúdo.